# Не отображаются последние изображения карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я использую API и получаю старые изображения некоторых мест, например изображения 2012 года. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы получить последние изображения? (Извините за язык, я использовал Google Translate)

Comment: Изображения? Спутниковые снимки старые? А на https://yandex.ru/maps есть снимки новее для выбранного вами района? Добавьте пример вашего кода, чтобы стало понятней, о чём идёт речь.

Comment: Я имел в виду спутниковые снимки мест. Внизу страницы написано название компании, которая предоставляет спутниковые снимки, и год снимков.

Comment: А второй вопрос? У Яндекса есть нужные вам снимки или нет? Если на публичной карте снимки старые, вопрос не к API, а к Яндексу. Но по заказу они снимки не закупают.

Comment: Изображения на Яндекс-картах тоже старые. Значит ли это, что нет возможности получить самые свежие спутниковые снимки через API, если снимки на Yandex.ru/maps тоже старые?

Comment: Возможности API не превышают возможностей публичной Яндекс Карты. Да, если на https://yandex.ru/maps спутниковые снимки старые, значит и через API более новых не получить.